# Apple HealthKit read Dietary Fibre using swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, swift5, healthkit, ios15

I am trying to read the nutrition details from Health Kit, but getting empty array and error when I query the HealthKit.

```
func getNutritionDetails() {
        let predicate = HKQuery.predicateForSamples(withStart: Date(), end: Date().addingTimeInterval(-1.0 * 60.0 * 60.0 * 24.0), options: .strictStartDate)
        
        let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(key: HKSampleSortIdentifierEndDate, ascending: true)
        
        let query = HKSampleQuery.init(
            sampleType: HKQuantityType.quantityType(forIdentifier: .dietaryFiber)!,
            predicate: predicate,
            limit: 0,
            sortDescriptors: [sortDescriptor]) { (query, samples, error) in
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print(samples, error)
                }
            }
        
        self.healthStore.execute(query)
    }
```

It prints `Optional([]) nil`
Also, what if I want to read the nutritions in one single query to HealthKit?

Comment: I did a quick test and it worked. Check your auth status and the date range for the data.

Comment: got the problem.. the bug lies in start and end date.. end date is before start date...